# .net mvc - How to make class method parameter (IQueryable) to be nullable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iqueryable

I have a class method that receives a queryable parameter:

```
public IQueryable<Company> getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(IQueryable<Company> companies, bool onlyActive = true)
{
    /*
    if (companies == null) {
        companies = db.companies;
    }
    */

    int userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
    companies = companies.Where(s => s.id_user == userId);

    if (onlyActive) {
        companies = companies.Where(e => e.active);
    }   
    return companies;
}
```

This is working ok, but now I need the parameter 'companies' to be optional... how can I do that?
I have tried with IQueryable? companies, but that gives an error:

```
the type IQueryable<Company> must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'
```

Comment: `companies = companies?.Where(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give companies parameter a default value (ie. null)

```
public IQueryable<Company> getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(IQueryable<Company> companies = null, bool onlyActive = true)
```

then your method can be called as follows

```
getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(companies, false);
getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(companies);
getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(onlyActive: false);
```

Comment: So simple, thank you.I was pretty sure i had tried that with no success, but it seems I was wrong. I will choose this answer as the correct one just for its simplicity, although I think all answers are correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can do overloads of your method so:

```
public IQueryable<Company> getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(bool onlyActive = true)
{
     return getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(db.companies, onlyActive);
}

public IQueryable<Company> getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(IQueryable<Company> companies, bool onlyActive = true)
{
    int userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
    companies = companies.Where(s => s.id_user == userId);

    if (onlyActive) {
        companies = companies.Where(e => e.active);
    }   
    return companies;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Em, just add null to the parameter:

```
public IQueryable<Company> getEmpresasVisiblesUsuario(IQueryable<Company> companies = null, bool onlyActive = true)
```